# Unable to destroy activity: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id () for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception, ondestroy

I have an activity `YYYY` (which inflates a fragment) that extends a base activity `XXXX` which in turn extends `ActionBarActivity`.
I now call `finish()` in `onCreate()` method of `XXXX` (at the very top), based on some condition. 
But I get the exception below. Kindly help me out.

PS: I call `return;` after the `finish();` so that the rest of the `onCreate()` is not executed.

```
07-26 16:46:26.902  14569-14569/E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c01ec (XXXXXXXX) for fragment XXXXXXXXXXXXXX{2c85cf32 #2 id=0x7f0c01ec}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c01ec (XXXXXXXXXXX) for fragment XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{2c85cf32 #2 id=0x7f0c01ec}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:945)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1963)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:313)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onDestroy(ActionBarActivity.java:166)
    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onDestroy(XXXXXXXXXXXX.java:100)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6132)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3745)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found out what the problem is. The first time around calling `finish()` works perfectly. The problem occurs when the application is killed by the system and is recreated. If it's just an activity that is getting recreated, calling `finish()` after `setContentView()` works fine.

But if the activity has some fragments inflated in it, then when this particular activity is killed, Android stores the states of the fragments also. But it does not save this in the FragmentManager but rather a different list. So when the activity is recreated, Android already knows what the fragments are. Hence we can't just simply destroy it before inflating the fragment. If we do that, we get the exception during `onDestroy()`

So the ideal place to call the `finish()` is not just after `setContentView()`, but also after the `onCreateView()` of the fragments. Thus I ended by calling `finish()` in the `onResume()` of the activity. Things work fine.

Though I have found out the solution, I can't seem to find how to clear the list of fragment history that Android maintains when activity is recreated. If I could clear that list, then I could call `finish()` in the `onCreate()` itself. This is something that I am still searching for.

Answer (score 1):

If you call *finish()* from *onCreate()* that doesnt mean that onStart and onResume are not getting called (activity is onFinishing actually).
To fix your issue u should call isFinishing() at onStart and onResume and if its true then return from that point.

Comment: I don't have anything in onStart and onResume. I am still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add finish() after setContentView()