# Android: finish() Activity Runtime Exception

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am closing an activity via finish().

It works fine on several devices but on a Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo running Android 4.4 I get the following issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3706)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:169)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
android.util.Log.e(Log.java:307)
com.ads.adstimer.fragment.Registration.RegistrationActivity.onDestroy(RegistrationActivity.java:214)
android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5623)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1123)
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3693)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:169)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have found two posts about that subject: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376783/why-am-i-getting-a-crash-when-exiting-my-activity), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636481/unable-to-destroy-activity-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-fo)
But they did not help me.

My activity code. Note that I am using [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro):

```
    public class RegistrationActivity extends AppIntro {

       private AsyncTaskRegisterInBackground registerPushToken;

       (...)

          @Override
            public void onDonePressed() {

               (...)
               if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                                registerPushToken = new AsyncTaskRegisterInBackground();
                                registerPushToken.setParams(activity, gcm, regid);
                                registerPushToken.execute();
                            }
               (...)

            }

    @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(String responseRegid) {
            try {
                // load authToken from Server: JsonObjectRequest

 builderOnFailureDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .title(getResources().getString(R.string.registrierung_dialog_registrieren_failure_retry_title))
                        .content(onFailureDialogContent)
                        .positiveText(getResources().getString(R.string.registrierung_dialog_registrieren_failure_retry_positive_text))
                        .negativeText(getResources().getString(R.string.registrierung_dialog_registrieren_failure_retry_negative_text))
                        .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                activity.finish();
                            }
                        }); 

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        try {
            onFailureDialog.dismiss();
            onSuccessDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Activity.onDestroy()", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Or is the reason for the problem the async task running in background?

Answer (score 2):

call `finish()` inside `runOnUiThread()`.

i.e.

replace

```
finish();
```

with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    finish()

                }
            });
```